# Adding a Shapes files as a Layer on Mapbox Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap

I have a `shapes file` from [here](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/master-plan-2014-region-boundary-web?resource_id=0bbbeedc-f7e1-46c6-bfe1-73f42220dea9). I wish to add it on a Map, similar to what is done on the web page. I am not quite sure how to proceed with it. I want to use it on Web and hence use JavaScript.

Someone suggested me to use the `shapes file` as a `Layer` on the map. But how to go about it? Anyone experience with `Mapbox`, `Leaflet` or `OSM` please guide.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to add the `shapes file` by uploading it as a [tileset](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-tileset/) to [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/).

It provided me with a `map Id` and `source-layer` name which I was able to add as a Layer on my Mapbox map as follows:

```
map.addLayer({
        id: '<id>',
        type: 'fill',
        source: {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'mapbox://<map-id>' //  Mapbox tileset Map ID
        },
        'source-layer': '<layer-name>', // name of tilesets
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#088',
            'fill-opacity': 0.8,
            'fill-outline-color': '#000'
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to load a SHP file and display it on a Leaflet / Mapbox.js map, you have several Leaflet [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-data-formats) that can make the task easy.

For example [leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) ([online demo](http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/) where you can drop your zipped SHP and DBF files).

The data source that you mention also provides KML format, which may be easier to use.

For KML, you can use for example [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore):

> universal format parser for Leaflet & Mapbox.js

```js
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([38, -102.0], 5);

omnivore.kml('a.kml').addTo(map);
```

Live example with Leaflet and leaflet-omnivore: https://plnkr.co/edit/KVXqBScBuIrAahg4VsGi?p=preview

Comment: nice example and tool. I was able to add the Shapes file as a layer using mapbox itself. I have described my method in my answer.