# How to render shapes after uploading shapefile as tileset on mapbox studio

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have uploaded a `shape file` to mapbox studio. How to render that shape file on a map?

I am taking data from [here](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/master-plan-2014-region-boundary-web?resource_id=0bbbeedc-f7e1-46c6-bfe1-73f42220dea9), and need to show exactly the same regions as shown on that map.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial https://www.mapbox.com/help/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-1/.

...padding to make this answer longer than 30 chars...

Comment: Nice tutorial. I did something similar as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714280/7116413